# Using javascript to set a class to a LI element

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, menu, highlight

I have a page with the following menu:

https://jsfiddle.net/dva4zo8t/

Based on which menu button is clicked, the color changes and I can "remember" (set) the color on a new page load:

```
$('[id*="button"]').click(function() {
    $('.topmenu-ul li').removeClass();
    $(this).addClass('topmenu-selected' + $('a', this).attr('class'));
});
```

I also want to "remember" (set) the submenu link (so when I click "Add Appointment" and the appropriate page loads, it needs to stay highlighted like this:

[image: example]

So what I basically want is to change the class of the sub li just as I do with the main buttons, for example:

```
$('#redbutton').addClass('topmenu-selectedred');
$('.topmenu-tab-appointments').show();
```

Any pointers will be very welcome!

Comment: when you click on new appointment sub-menu the page maybe loaded so you cant just remember it using javascript you might need to store it in cookie and then retrieve and set it

Comment: With "remember" I actually mean just setting it on the new page that is loaded, like I do with the colored main buttons as well:     $('#redbutton').addClass('topmenu-selectedred');
    $('.topmenu-tab-appointments').show();

Comment: okay then you can use parent function of jquery to apply your color

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I try to answere your question. I have created fiddle.
I added following method in your code.

```
$('ul > li > a').click(function() {
    if(!$(this).hasClass("parent")) {
       $(this).css('color','red');
       $(this).parent().siblings().children().css('color','black');
    }
});
```

[Link for Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/dva4zo8t/3/)

Comment: Thanks, it works but I am looking for something I can use for when the page loads, to highlight the appropriate button. I will accept your answer though since it does work, but I will just need to look further :)